# Can you help me fix it? NameError: name 'data1' is not defined

Tags: python, linked-list

```
def mergeLists(curf, curs):
    dummyNode = Node(0)
    tail = dummyNode
    while True:
        if curf is None:
            tail.next = curs
            break
        if curs is None:
            tail.next = curf
            break

        if data1.dat[:2] <= data2.dat[:2]:
            if int(data1.dat[:2]) == int(data2.dat[:2]):
                sum = int(data1.dat[-2:]) + int(data2.dat[-2:])
                data1.dat = data1.dat[:-2] + " " + str(sum)

            tail.next = curf
            curf = curf.next
        else:
            tail.next = curs
            curs = curs.next
        tail = tail.next
```

Comment: It's telling you what the error is. data1 is not defined anywhere. Where have you defined that variable?

Comment: `data1` isn't defined anywhere in the code you have posted.

Comment: f = open("data1.dat","r")
s = open("data2.dat","r")

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined or initialized data1 and data2 variables. Try to initialize it it will work.

Comment: I'm a beginner who doesn't understand much

Comment: what is there inside data1 variable?